# function hoisting shows different results with and without block scope

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, scope, hoisting

This is the example:

```js
function b() {
  console.log(f); 

  {
    function f() {}
  }
}

b()
```

I thought it would become:

```
function b() {
  // hoist to function scope
  function f() {}
  console.log(f); // should output function f
}
```

or

```
function b() {
  console.log(f); // should output reference error
  {
     // just hoist to block scope like this
     function f() {}
  }
}
```

but it outputs undefined, like `var` hoisting. why?

Comment: Function declarations haven't been allowed before ES2015, but browsers still supported it, but every browser did this differently. ES2015 describes this behavior in an appendix: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics . Depending on the context (non-strcit vs strict), the function declaration is basically evaluated as a variable declaration that is assigned a function expression. In strict mode this code throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` creates block scope so

JS engine will interpret your code something like this

```
function b() {
  console.log(f);
  {
    var f = function f() {};
  }
}

b();
```

So because of block scoping value of `f` is not available out of block. and since it is defined as var it is hoisted to parent's scope ( function b's scope ) and turns out to be undefined

If you remove `{}` .

```js
function b() {
  console.log(f); 
  function f() {}
}

b()
```

Comment: Should be `var f = ...` in the first example. *"it is hoisted to global scope"* No, it's not global it's hoisted inside the function's (`b`) scope.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah i just forgot to remove `_`'s after copying from babel repl. updated thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: Remove ```{}``` inside ```function b()```. This is because console statement is out of the scope of the declaration of function f()

Answer (score 0):

It's due to Hoisting. The `function f() {}` is inside a block, therefore console.log(f) cannot access the `function f() {}`, that is out of the scope. However, if you keep the `console.log(f)` inside the block `{}`. Hoisting should work.

Comment: The question is "how does hoisting work here" and you are basically saying "it's because of hoisting". It's not really an explanation of what's going on.